# Play! Framework app on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, playframework

I want to deploy and run my Play! Framework app on EC2.

I have installed the Play! Framework on one instance, now I don't want to copy my source code over but instead I want to "build" my app into libraries/jar/wars and copy the binary over and have play run against the binaries. Does Play! support that?

Comment: You should check out Heroku.  Makes it really easy to run Play! apps on the Cloud.  http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play

Comment: @JamesWard gets trickier once you build something for EU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no native single-file format for play apps.

But, yes you can use any archive format for your purpose. Instead of running :

```
play command myfile
```

you'll do something like this :

```
unzip myfile; play command file;
```

Plus, you could always try using wars and rune those across multiple tomcats, but it would be a waste of ressources as native play server is better.

Answer (score 10):

You can deploy your play application as standalone java application without installing play framework on EC2. You will need to generate distribution file of your play application by following step

1. Navigate to project folder
2. type **play**
3. type **dist**

This will generate project snapshot zip file in dist folder of your play application.

Upload that zip file to EC2 instance and extract in some folder. There you will find a **start** shell script file. Just execute that script file

Note: **To make file executable type: chmod 777 start**

**./start**

This will publish application and opens port to receive http request on default port 9000. If you want to change port when executing file,

**./start -Dhttp.port=8080**

This will publish application on port 8080

Comment: Is the dist method really the best way to deploy apps to ec2? It seems that even with a small Play app the dist size is quite large and so to scp to multiple instances will take quite some time.

Also, running with ./start doesn't seem to fork the process. Do you typically run with '&' to fork it?

Comment: 777 is world-readable, writeable, which may not be ideal (though it hardly matters on ec2) 755 might be a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the [Play documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/deployment) mention it clearly that you can.

```
play war myapp -o myapp.war
```

Take a look on Play documentation, its very clear.

Comment: That's for getting hosted in servlets - eg. tomcat. What I wanted is to still hosted by Play! but no source code.

Comment: As far as I know that is only for play 1 applications, play 2 no longer support running war fles.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `activator` you can exploit its `stage` command which prepares all dependent libraries and compiles your code.

In my blog, I have tried to explain the whole deployment scenario of an Play application to an EC2 instance. Here is the link for more detail:

http://www.javacirecep.com/cloud/deploy-play-scala-applications-on-amazon-ec2/